# SNMP Get routes on Checkpoint returns integer value for IPADDRESS field

Tags: snmp, ip-address, checkpoint

I'm trying to execute SNMP-Get request on Checkpoint to get IP address of a route with OID `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2620.1.6.51.1.2`. [Here](http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.2620.1.6.51.1.2) we can see that syntax of this field is `SYNTAX IpAddress`. However, when I execute `snmpget` I receive an Integer value:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2620.1.6.51.1.2.1.0 = INTEGER: 50594820
```

What can be the problem? Or is it possible to decode this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses *are* integers (whole numbers). IPv4 addresses are 32-bit integers, and IPv6 addresses are 128-bit integers.

I assume that this is for an IPv4 address. To look at it as a dotted decimal address, take the binary 32 bits of the integer:

```
00000011000001000000010000000100
```

separate the octets with decimals:

```
00000011.00000100.00000100.00000100
```

and convert each octet to decimal:

```
3.4.4.4
```

You should always do IP address manipulation in binary. See [How do you calculate the prefix, network, subnet, and host numbers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499)